# "Expected Long but got Int" while running PyTorch script

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am facing this error while running a pytorch script.

Can anyone help me?

```
Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Int for argument #2 'target'
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you are running.

Comment: "This error" isn't a title that lets anyone else know if they have the same error. And see the [mcve] definition for discussion of what a question should include to ensure that there's enough context to answer it.