# Pytorch expected type Long but got type int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

I revived an error

```
 Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Int for argument #3 'index'
```

This is from this line.

```
targets = torch.zeros(log_probs.size()).scatter_(1, targets.unsqueeze(1).data.cpu(), 1)
```

I am not sure what to do as I tried to convert this to a long using several places. I tried putting a

```
.long
```

at the end as well as setting the dtype to be torch.long which still didn't work.

Very similar to this but he didn't do anything to get the answer
["Expected Long but got Int" while running PyTorch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262455/expected-long-but-got-int-while-running-pytorch-script)

I have change a lot of the code and here is my last rendition, but is now giving me the same issue.

```
    def forward(self, inputs, targets):
            """
            Args:
                inputs: prediction matrix (before softmax) with shape (batch_size, num_classes)
                targets: ground truth labels with shape (num_classes)
            """
            log_probs = self.logsoftmax(inputs)
            targets = torch.zeros(log_probs.size()).scatter_(1, targets.unsqueeze(1).data.cpu(), 1)
            if self.use_gpu: targets = targets.to(torch.device('cuda'))
            targets = (1 - self.epsilon) * targets + self.epsilon / self.num_classes
            loss = (- targets * log_probs).mean(0).sum()
            return loss
```

Comment: The question you referenced is ~5 months old. It's unlikely they just sat about for this time. Drop a comment on the question to see if they found a solution

Comment: Long is not supported in python 3 anymore so try int(var_name) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dtype of your index argument (i.e., `targets.unsqueeze(1).data.cpu()`) needs to be `torch.int64`.

(The error message is a bit confusing: `torch.long` doesn't exist. But "Long" in PyTorch internals means int64).

Comment: how do I do that? I know in java it like this int(x); but I tried something similar with python and it didnt work. Any suggestions? I also tried adding dtype= int64 to it but that didnt work either.

Comment: "I also tried adding dtype= int64 to it but that didnt work either." can you show the exact code you used?

Comment: targets = torch.int64(torch.zeros(log_probs.size()).scatter_(1, targets.unsqueeze(1).data.cpu(), 1))

Comment: targets = torch.zeros(log_probs.size()).scatter_(1, torch.int64(targets.unsqueeze(1).data.cpu()), 1)

Comment: targets = torch.int64(log_probs.size()).scatter_(1, targets.unsqueeze(1).data.cpu(), 1)

Comment: targets = torch.zeros(log_probs.size(), dtype=torch.int64).scatter_(1, targets.unsqueeze(1).data.cpu(), 1)

Comment: targets = torch.zeros(log_probs.size(),dtype=torch.long).scatter_(1, targets.unsqueeze(1).data.cpu(), 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
targets = torch.zeros(log_probs.size()).scatter_(1, (targets.unsqueeze(1).data.cpu()).long(), 1)
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for sharing an answer!
For the future, adding an explanation for the answer will definitely help out! :)